# Screen scraping site to new browser window

Tags: asp.net, screen-scraping

I am not sure whether what I am asking is possible or not. I have internal Sharepoint site which can be accessible through valid Credentials(Windows/SQL Authentication) only.

From Test ASP.NET web Application I performed Login Screen scraping and get _VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, __EVENTVALIDATION etc and then provide Credentials and prepared PostData and able to get cookies and finally able to login successfully into secured Page. I got secured page html source code.

Now, I need to launch it in separate browser window so that secure page will open as it is and then subsequently all page links work properly.

When I written `Response.Write(responseData);` the page source(html) open in current Test ASP.NET web application.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but here is my thought.

In order to open the SharePoint site (the response HTML) in a new window, you could move the code to another .aspx page that is dedicated to performing the screen scrape and nothing else. Back on the original .aspx page, use Javascript to open the second .aspx page in a new window. The new window will open and the screen scrape will process.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open("secondPage.aspx");">Click here to launch SharePoint</a>
```

If the SharePoint links are relative, you'll need to parse the SharePoint response and replace all of the relative links with absolute links. This can be achieved with HTML Agility Pack pretty easily. This example replaces the src attribute but this can be modified to replace href attributes as well:

```
Private Function MakeUrlsAbsolute(html As String) As String
    Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
    Dim url As String
    Dim uri As Uri

    doc.LoadHtml(html)

    For Each node As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.Descendants.Where(Function(d) d.Attributes.Contains("src")).ToList()
        url = node.GetAttributeValue("src", "")

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url) Then
            uri = New Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)

            If Not uri.IsAbsoluteUri Then
                uri = New Uri(New Uri("https://www.yourSharePointSite.com/"), uri)

                node.SetAttributeValue("src", uri.ToString())
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
End Function
```